# Resolve class ActionLogging , unable to find class for annotation

Tags: java, grails, annotations, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm using Grails 3.1.9 and IntellJ 2017,
I want to use the plug-in:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:action-logging:1.1.1"
```

I downloaded it correctly. I add it in my controller, as the manual said:

```
package com.test

import org.mirzsoft.grails.actionlogging.annotation.*

class TestController {

    @ActionLogging
    @SpringUserIdentification
    def index() {

        }
    }
}
```

I see it in the packages downloaded, but once I try to compile, I got these message:

```
: 34: unable to resolve class ActionLogging ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 34, column 5.
       @ActionLogging
```

The annotation are imported, as far as I know.
any clue?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

That plugin has not been updated to support Grails 3 - You can find Grails 3 plugins at http://plugins.grails.org/ - You might try updating the plugin yourself or open an issue and ask if the author plans to update it to support Grails 3.

Source is at https://github.com/erickmorales3/action-logging